# using jssc and java applet to communicate to Serial with JS but browser freezes

Tags: java, javascript, applet, serial-port

Im trying to talk to the serial port with JS using a java applet.  Im not too experienced with java but i managed to get jssc running just fine when not in a applet or using js.  and Ive also been able to talk between an applet and JS passing functions and variables.  but I cannot understand why my browers freezes everytime i try to load the serialCom.class applet that contains the jssc information

here is my java

```
import jssc.SerialPort;
import jssc.SerialPortException;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;



public class serialCom extends Applet{


SerialPort serialPort;


public void connect(){
    serialPort = new SerialPort("/dev/pts/2");
    try {
        serialPort.openPort();
        serialPort.setParams(9600, 8, 1, 0);
        serialPort.writeBytes("Hello Again".getBytes());
        serialPort.closePort();
        }
    catch (SerialPortException ex){
        System.out.print(ex);
        }
}
public void disconnect(){
    //SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort("/dev/pts/1");
    try {
        //serialPort.openPort();
        //serialPort.setParams(9600, 8, 1, 0);
        //serialPort.writeBytes("Hello Again".getBytes());
        serialPort.closePort();
        }
    catch (SerialPortException ex){
        System.out.print(ex);
        }
}
public void writeSerial(){
     //SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort("/dev/pts/1");
    try {
        //serialPort.openPort();
        //serialPort.setParams(9600, 8, 1, 0);
        serialPort.writeBytes("Hello Again".getBytes());
        //serialPort.closePort();
        }
    catch (SerialPortException ex){
        System.out.print(ex);
        }
}





}
```

and here is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>
 Will It Work
</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<button id="test" onclick="connectTest();">Connect</button>
<button id="test" onclick="writeTest();">Write</button>
<button id="test" onclick="readTest();">Read</button>
<button id="test" onclick="disconnectTest();">Disconnect</button>
<applet code="serialCom.class" id="myApplet" width="0" height="0"></applet>
 <script>
var connectTest = function(){
alert("Im Connected");
myApplet.connect();

}
alert("Connect");
var disconnectTest = function(){
alert("Im Disconnected");
myApplet.disconnect();
}
alert("Disconnect");
var writeTest = function(){
alert("Im Writing");
myApplet,writeSerial();
}
alert("Write");
var readTest = function(){
}
alert("Read");
</script>-->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1) Please don't forget to add a '?' to questions!  Some people do a search in the page for '?' and if none exists in the 'question' go directly to the next (actual) question in line.  2) A single blank line of white space in source code is *always* enough.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite new to all this java applet programming, but its seems like we are trying to do something similar. I have no idea what exactly is wrong with your code but I found [jss-bridge](https://code.google.com/p/java-simple-serial-connector/source/browse/trunk/js_terminal/jssc-bridge.js) which helped me a lot on achieving serial port communication trough javascript/java-applet.

you can download the full code using svn

```
svn checkout http://java-simple-serial-connector.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ java-simple-serial-connector-read-only
```

inside the js_terminal folder you will find an index.html that simulates a terminal on your browser to communicate with the serial ports. it works amazingly well.
you will also probably need to lower your java security setting or self-sign the applet.

I hope it helps!

pd: I know it isn't an answer, but i can't comment yet.